# Unable to track call stack of JavaScript async-await

Tags: javascript

I wrote a code and try to come up with an expected answer to understand asynchronous behavior.

I numbered the console.log lines in a way I thought it should appear, but it printed line no. 6 before line no. 5

Actual output is:

- outside before calling **1**
- wrapper before calling **2**
- inside waiter before calling setTimeout **3**
- inside waiter after calling setTimeout **4**
- outside after calling ***6***
- wrapper after calling ***5***
- after 2 sec received:  Hi There

I thought it would come as lines numbered in code. But line no. 5 and 6 are swapped in actual execution.
can anyone explain why?

```
let waiter=async function (msg){
    console.log('inside waiter before calling setTimeout 3')
    setTimeout(()=>{
        console.log('after 2 sec received: ',msg)
    }, 2000);
    console.log('inside waiter after calling setTimeout 4')
}

async function wrapper(){
    console.log('wrapper before calling 2')
    await waiter('Hi There')
    console.log('wrapper after calling 5')
}

console.log('outside before calling 1')
wrapper();
console.log('outside after calling 6')
```

Comment: Why did you expect `6` to be last? You're not dealing with the promise `wrapper` returns at all.

Comment: Hi, this was a pretty well laid out question, except that it's missing a question. Make sure to actually ask a question somewhere. Stating the problem is essential, but what do you want to know.

Comment: `async` function return values are wrapped in a promise, so you need to `await wrapper()`.

Comment: Huh, until now, I thought calls to async functions got put on the waiting list but it seems they're called synchronously until the first `await`... TIL

Comment: It is executing console.log numbered lines as :   1->2->3->4->**6**->**5**       .could anyone please explain the reason of printing lines in this order?

Answer (score 0):

Because `wrapper` is asynchronous and you are not `await`-ing it for it to complete, code execution continues as normal, so 6 is logged before 5.

To have the 5 logged before 6, wait for `wrapper` to complete with `await`:

```js
console.log('outside before calling 1');
await wrapper();
console.log('outside after calling 6');
```

Comment: Hi @youdateme ,     if we await-ing wrapper, then we need to put it in async function as well or face error.    But what I more like to know is THE reason of why lines come in this particular order 1->->2->3->4->6->5     .Could you please explain it.

Comment: You don’t wait for wrapper to complete so the 6th console log goes ahead and runs anyways. That’s why if I use am await there it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The function that is calling `wrapper` must either `return` or `await` something in order for JavaScript to relinquish control of execution back to the event loop.  The handler you provided to `setTimeout` is initiated by the event loop and that can't start executing until the function you're currently calling either returns or awaits.

Since you did not `await` the call to `wrapper`, this function just returns a promise, which you ignore / discard by not making use of the return value of `wrapper()`.  And execution continues past it to your `6` waypoint before the timeout handler will execute.

If the function in which all your example code resides is `async` then you could do:

```
console.log('outside before calling 1');
await wrapper();
console.log('outside after calling 6');
```

If `await` is not available at that level, then you could use `.then` to have something be executed when the promise completes.

```
let waiter=async function (msg){
    console.log('inside waiter before calling setTimeout 3')
    setTimeout(()=>{
        console.log('after 2 sec received: ',msg)
    }, 2000);
    console.log('inside waiter after calling setTimeout 4')
}

async function wrapper(){
    console.log('wrapper before calling 2')
    await waiter('Hi There')
    console.log('wrapper after calling 5')
}

console.log('outside before calling 1');
wrapper().then(() => {
   consolelog('promise returned by wrapper is now complete 6');
});
console.log('this will still happen before 5 (call it 4b)');
```

Comment: Thanks @Wyck, I got the concept of 5 coming before 6. You explained it very well.    Could you also explain the complete execution? By including states of call stack and event loops?  It will really  help me out in digesting this whole code